# Google Admin SDK user push notifications and renaming of users

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I want to ask about the situation that is related to the renaming of a user by an administrator. It can take up to 10 minutes (from the disclaimer) to get user's name changed, but the notification about update event is sent immediately. There is no way to understand whether user's data is changed or not at the moment when notification is received. The only way to process it correctly is to delay processing by 10 minutes which is not good for me.

Is there something that I've missed to handle this? Otherwise it is quite useless API.

Comment: Have you actually tested this with a working demo?

Comment: Sure, that's why I've posted my question. Sometimes user's name is changing almost instantly and I can get new data through API call soon after notification has come. But often it takes few seconds or even few minutes until I get changed data as response to the API call.